# How to implement a simple telnet client in C to send command to server

Tags: c, shell, telnet

I want to use telnet to send shell command or execute shell scripts on server automatically,
 any one have done such problem? can you share your experience?

Comment: You should be sharing your experience here - let us know what doesn't work for you.

Comment: Its like, I want to summit Mt, Everest! Can you share your experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about socket communication. You need to know how socket works. Then, implement [Telnet protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) by yourself.

If you don't want to implement your own telnet libraries. You might download [putty source](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html) and see if you could leverage from it.